# Security: Static Library (.lib) vs Dynamic Link Library (.dll)

Tags: c++, dll, static-libraries

At present I am in a situation where I had to include an `SMTP Library` and `Database details` for `sending an Email` and `Inserting data into my Database` from client side in an normal `C++ Console based app`. My major concern is, I don't want my data in the `.exe` to be read by tools such as `PE Explorer etc`, so I've decided to include the DB details such as `hostname, password, dbname, tablename` AND SMTP details such as `username, password etc` in a library, link it and not in that EXE directly. Is this the secured way or is there any other way around to perform this task?

If yes, which one to use - a `.lib` or a `.dll`?

Please clarify,
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Static linking means actually putting the code from the library in the resulting executable. But dynamic linking using a DLL will not help either, as anyone could just use e.g. PE Explorer on the DLL instead.

Comment: if you put the data in a dll, your data is simply in the dll now instead of your exe. So just as easy to read with PE Explorer etc. If you put it in a static lib, the linker will put the dta back in your exe so nothing gained either.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way I could accomplish the task??

Comment: You could encrypt data, so it will be harder to extract it. However, whatever you do - at some point decrypted data have to be in memory, and in this moment it could easily be stolen. Or intercept network traffic. Or something else - anything could be broken, the question is how much effort it will require.

Comment: Go easy on the `backtick`, your question just gets too hard to read.

Comment: @HansPassant Sir, I am just `backticking` the important parts of my question...

Comment: Hi all, I thought of following: I will built a Client-Server application, client - C++ and server - php. On receiving data from Client, I can do whatever I want like sending email, inserting in DB etc. Can it be the best way??? - Awaiting comments/ replies/ suggestions, please guide me, Thank you...